# Dynamic Horizontal Partitioning in MYSQL RDS

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

**Problem statement**

1. I have a table in mysql database setup in AWS RDS, which is expected to grow to a very large dataset
2. I have a datetime column on which I need to horizontally partition so as to divide the table rows on yearly basis (or number of rows perhaps?).
3. More partitions should preferably be created automatically as the data and time progresses.

The main idea is that while querying the rows I should avoid searching the entire table, in stead should be able to limit search set to only for the year asked in query.

I have been searching over internet but only find limited resources on this task, most search results end up telling only a definite amount of partitions.

**My Limitations**

1. I do not control the setup and configuration of RDS Instance (It could be the last resort)
2. While running `SHOW PLUGINS` it doesn't shows `partition` in the list.

What are my options? Any help would be great.

Comment: `divide the table rows on yearly basis` Create partitions up to 2100 year. And when one finally need to add more partitions, it will be NOT YOUR problem.